# Can JQuery do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a div and remove it after 5 seconds, the problem i have is that myscript is removing all the divs at the same time, and I want you to remove the divs in order of creation, one by one.

Here my script until now:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".create").click(function(){
  
  //HERE I CREATE THE DIVS
  $('.divs').append('<div class="deleteon5seconds">Hello</div>');
  //HERE FINISH CREATE THE DIVS
  
  });
});

//HERE I DELETE THE DIVS IF IT EXIST
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var $articleCount = $('.deleteon5seconds').length; 

    while ($articleCount > 0) {
        $('.deleteon5seconds:last-child').remove();
        $articleCount = $('.deleteon5seconds').length;
    }

    $autoUpdate();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="create">Create</button>
<div class="divs"></div>
```

All this is an example, the purpose of the code is to show alerts. I need help please!
Advanced thanks!!

Comment: It's a little unclear _exactly_ what you want to have happen. Do you want each div to be removed 5 seconds after it appears? Or do you want just one div to disappear every five seconds? Or do you want all the divs that were created in a five second window to disappear? Or something else?

Comment: @MattBurland Hi, I want delete the divs by order, removed each div 5 seconds after it appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand what you are asking, for each div created, you will need to get a reference to that new div and then use `setTimeout` (not `setInterval`) for each one with an interval of 5 seconds that will remove that particular div. This make it so each new div will live for 5 seconds and  then disappear.

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".create").click(function(){
  
  //HERE I CREATE THE DIVS
  var div = $('.divs').append('<div class="deleteon5seconds">Hello' + count++ + '</div>');
  var elem = $('.divs div.deleteon5seconds').last();
  //HERE FINISH CREATE THE DIVS

  setTimeout(() => elem.remove(), 5000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="create">Create</button>
<div class="divs"></div>
```

I added the `count` part just to make it easier to keep track of which div is which.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the first created element of that class with $('div.deleteon5seconds').first().remove();

> .first() 
>   Description: Reduce the set of matched
>   elements to the first in the set.

The problem here is that you have added while and it deletes them all. 
Check my fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".create").click(function(){
  
  //HERE I CREATE THE DIVS
  $('.divs').append('<div class="deleteon5seconds">Hello</div>');
  //HERE FINISH CREATE THE DIVS
  
  });
});

//HERE I DELETE THE DIVS IF IT EXIST
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var articleCount = $('.deleteon5seconds').length; 

    if (articleCount > 0) {
    
        $('div.deleteon5seconds:first-of-type').remove();
        articleCount = $('.deleteon5seconds').length;
    }

}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="create">Create</button>
<div class="divs"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I just try it and it dont work!!

Comment: Could you try with
$(document).find('div.deleteon5seconds').first().remove();

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but I can't make it